# Google Fit live data sync

Tags: flutter, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

I have integrated google fit with flutter and i'm getting steps count properly when my application is active but its not getting synced after closing my app. i want to run a background serivce which will sync my steps count and heart points with the application.

This application is for both OS android and IOS but Ios is restricting to do this.

I want to sync live data with my app for android and IOS both, if its possible through background service or any other method i'm ready to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Google library or an iOS-provided third-party library? In addition, it is important to note that the Fit Android API has been deprecated and will cease to function by the end of 2024. Migration from the Fit Android API to the Health Connect API is strongly advised.

https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect-guidelines/migrate/migration-guide